# Path to send resized images on upload php

Tags: php, path, image-uploading

I have a simple multiple image upload script that resizes images maintaining the aspect ratio. The resizing is working fine. however, **I can't seem to send the images to the correct folder, even though the syntax is correct.**

Here is what i'm doing in a nutshell:

if file input "Image" is not empty then create a new folder within "../company_images" the name of the created folder is a uniqid defined by the "$photo_directory_name" variable. after this run the resize function for each of the images then put the resized images in to the upload folder defined by the "$total_path" variable.

```
if(!empty($_FILES["Image"])){

$photo_directory_name = uniqid(rand(100, 1000));    
$photos_path = "company_images/" . $photo_directory_name;       
$directory = "../company_images/";      

if (!file_exists($directory . $photo_directory_name)) {
$upload_dir = mkdir($directory . $photo_directory_name, 0777, TRUE);
}else{
$upload_dir = $directory . $photo_directory_name;
}       


function resize($width, $height){   

  /* Get original image x y*/
  list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']);
  /* calculate new image size with ratio */
  $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
  $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
  $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
  $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
  /* new file name */   
  $path =  $width.'x'.$height.'_'.$_FILES['Image']['name']; 

  $total_path = $directory . $photo_directory_name . $path; 


  /* read binary data from image file */
  $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']);
  /* create image from string */
  $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
  $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
    0, 0,
    $x, 0,
    $width, $height,
    $w, $h);
  /* Save image */
  switch ($_FILES['Image']['type']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
      imagejpeg($tmp, $total_path, 100);
      break;
    case 'image/png':
      imagepng($tmp, $total_path, 0);
      break;
    case 'image/gif':
      imagegif($tmp, $total_path);
      break;
    default:
      exit;
      break;
  }
  return $total_path;
  /* cleanup memory */
  imagedestroy($image);
  imagedestroy($tmp);
}       


$max_file_size = 1024*1000; // 1mb
$valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
// thumbnail sizes
$sizes = array(1200 => 1000);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' AND isset($_FILES['Image'])) {
  if( $_FILES['Image']['size'] < $max_file_size ){

    // get file extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['Image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {


      /* resize image */
      foreach ($sizes as $w => $h) {
        $files[] = resize($w, $h);
      }

    } else {
     $response["message"] = 'photos_invalid_format';
     $errors++; 
    }
  } else{
    $response["message"] = 'photos_file_too_large';
    $errors++; 
  }
}
echo $total_path;   

}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So the resized images get stored in the wrong folder?  Which folder?

Comment: if nothing is saved it's probably a permissions / access denied error.  On many systems PHP now runs as "nobody" not the apache / ftp / WWW user.

Comment: @James yes that is correct. It is storing them in company_images, not company_images/ $photo_directory_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some global variables that you're using inside the resize function:

```
$directory 
$photo_directory_name
```

They need to be either passed in as parameters, or declared as globals within that function:

```
function resize($width, $height){   
  global $directory, $photo_directory_name;
  // rest of function
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve the problem. It's creating the new folder, however is still placing the images in company_images.

Comment: I think this line `$total_path = $directory . $photo_directory_name . $path;` is not working correctly.  My answer gives one possible explanation but there could be others.  Try to debug that line and check the value of `$total_path` is what you are expecting.